# How can We do Remote MSSQL Server Database Connection With Linux Hostin On PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, web-hosting, host

How can I connect to MSSQL Remote Database connection on Linux Hosting Server with php?

I am using odbc_connect function on php to mssql server database connection.

Here it is:

```
odbc_connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=***;DATABASE=***;CharSet=utf8','***','***');
```

And my Hosting COntrol Panel Plesk Parallels Panel.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using PDO or `mssql_connect` ?

Comment: Is it possible with PDO AND how it is?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: Tuncay diyorsun ki PDO kullanabiliriz?

Comment: @user3763026 Please write in English.

Comment: OK.PDO doesnt work !

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) . It is a way to connect to SQL Server from *nix machines.

Comment: But Im trying to connect mssql on Linux Hosting (Plesk):Not Localhost.So Can we use freeTDS on Linux Hosting and How it is?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, there is no MS SQL Server implementation that can run on a *nix machine, so, yes, this FreeTDS is a software library to connect your Unix/Linux client machine to a MS SQL database on a Windows server machine. That means, by definition, it would not be localhost.

Same library connects to Sybase as well, I dont know if they have a *nix port, but I guess thats beside the point.

Comment: Ok.But I couldnt find How Can I use freeTDS.Can you Illustrate this?

Comment: You might want to read up on http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php which is the PHP module that uses FreeTDS. Also http://www.freetds.org/userguide/php.htm might be of help if you dont have the module and need to install it into PHP.

Comment: Infact My Question How Can I Install FreeTDS on Linux Web Host? I tried to putty but doesnt work

Comment: check the two links I gave.